# How to send Google cloud messaging message to other devices without logic on 3rd party server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make a simple messaging app that has a mysql and php server with an android app. My back end revolves around mysql to store and php to communicate from the database to the device and vise versa.

Now, what I am trying to accomplish is this: sending device->GCM->target device.

What I had in mind was that the database I created stores the gcm Id for all user. That way, when a user wants to send a message, their app sends a message to my database to be stored and retrieves the targets gcm Id and then sends the targets gcm id to the gcm servers to create the push notificiation. When the target receives the gcm message, it sends a response to the database to receive the actual sent message.

Is this possible, and how would I go about doing this?

I already have a gcm receiver implemented from here:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging

Comment: So, if I read this right, you want to go from phone to GCM to other device, which reads from your server? It's probably possible, but hard to answer with the details that you've included in your question.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Will add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Don't do it.

For any internet connected device (server or mobile) to request a push to a device, it needs to send a `POST` request to the GCM address (https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send) passing the server API key and the device GCM reg id which should receive the message. And having any of those values available on a device is a security risk for your application.

Having your registration ID, means ppl could easily "copy" your ID and start sending messages from their servers on your behalf.

The GCM device registraion ID, means anyone could start spaming your users, and you certainly don't want that.

You could look into GCM Upstream (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream) but that only means your client code will be easier, as it's as simple as calling `gcm.send(String);`, but you still have to handle that on your server application.

The correct way is to have on your server a table that maps `userId` with `gcmRegId` and have devices send to your server messages to their desired `userId`. Your server should process one device "send" message and create a push to the other device. That logic should be fairly simple on the server side, after you already have a whole chat application developed.

Comment: I have a working application, I am on the gcm aspect right now. Would this work for server logic? https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017

Comment: I'm not a server guy, I'm an Android dev guy. So I'm not sure if that code workd. But all it takes from `user1` to press send and `user2` receive, is: `device1` sends `POST` to your server with message and `user2_Id` (that's the ID on your own service -> Your server receives the message and add it to the chat database -> your server does a `POST` to Google servers asking to send a push to `regId_2` -> google does its thing -> `device2` receives the push